# Links with an Image above the Text

Tags: html

How can i make a link display a centered image/icon above the text? Something like this:

[image: Link Image Above Text]

If possible without using CSS `background: url('image path');` because i have many links, with different images.

I tried it like this

```
<a href=""><img src="http://www.biswanathcollege.org/templates/rt_crystalline_j15/images/icons/icon-home.png" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" />hello</a>
```

But it doesn't work properly, the link stretches the full width of the parent container.

Comment: can we have the html and css you've done so far

Comment: @bojangles sory about that, edited now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want a simple icon over a link

take a look at this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/RockRathore/63s6w/3/

```
<div style="border:1px solid;width:200px;background:#FAF9F2">
<div style="text-align:center">
    <a href="your_link.php">
        <img src="http://www.biswanathcollege.org/templates/rt_crystalline_j15/images/icons/icon-home.png" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;";/>
            Hello
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but i need the icon to be inside the link, so it will be "clickable" :)